# Data size vs index size

Tags: mongodb, analytics

We have a mongodb database backing website analytics. I have noticed the index size being the half if total data size: 20GB index, 40GB data. Is this normal state? What is typical for such databases?

Comment: There is no typical ratio of data to indexes: the outcome depends on a number of factors specific to your deployment, data, and use case. Are you trying to infer this number for planning purposes or just curious on the ratio you've observed for your use case? Are these web analytics collected by a standard application (eg. Sitecore CMS) or custom to your application? You could review your [`db.collection.stats()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/) output to get a better understanding of relative `indexSizes` for your use case.

Comment: Analytics is gathered by Sitecore. I am looking for a way to optimize both storage and load.  Right now server has 16G RAM and I see around 20k page faults (in opsmanager) being nearly constant. Need to decide on vertical vs horizontal scaling. What other metrics would be helpful to check out?